# TabMain is not abstract and does not override abstract method onTabReselected(Tab,FragmentTransaction) in TabListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, swipeview

Good day guys. I'm trying to build a simple app which support tab layout with a swipe view feature. I follow this [tutorial](http://techlovejump.com/android-tab-layout-swipe-views-tutorial-example/) but no success.

```
package com.example.project.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class TabMain extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabsFragmentPagerAdapter tabsAdapter;
    private String[] days = new String[]{"Information","Claim"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabsAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(days[i]).setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }


    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I have follow each single step from the tutorial, but I get error as below.

```
Error:(13, 8) error: TabMain is not abstract and does not override abstract method onTabReselected(Tab,FragmentTransaction) in TabListener
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

And I get a red line underneath this statement `public class TabMain extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong `FragmentTransaction` class for that interface, which uses `android.app.FragmentTransaction`, not `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction`. Since the your method signature doesn't match the interface's, you're not actually implementing the correct method. The old `ActionBar` and it's related classes don't work with those support classes.

[`ActionBar.TabListener` docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html)

Please note that that class had been deprecated, and Google recommends that you change how you handle navigation within your app.

Comment: Nah, it's not a stupid mistake. It's quite easy to get those mixed up, since they kept the same class names in the support package. Things got a little confusing when they released that library.

Comment: @John I neglected to mention that, if you do want to keep ActionBar tabs,  the v7 support package has a [replacement for that interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html).